# Parsing CSV string and binding it to listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have splitted comma separated values in an string array, something like this

```
str[0] ="210"
str[1] ="abc.pdf"
str[2] = "211"
str[3] = "xyz.docx"
```

and so on. Please note 0,2,4,6,8 [even positions] are having number and odd positions are having string.

I am having a class Attachmodel

Public Class AttachmentModel

```
Private _attachmentID As Integer = 0
Private _attachmentPath As String = ""

''' <summary>
''' Get Set Attachment ID
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>

Public Property AttachmentID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _attachmentID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _attachmentID = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Get Set Attachment Path
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>

Public Property AttachmentPath() As String
    Get
        Return _attachmentPath
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _attachmentPath = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

In the above i want to set the values and bind it to the grid, using List

Comment: thanks, I have solved it any ways. I am posting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to bind CSV string with listbox programmatically

```
Private Sub BindAttachmentsToListBox(ByVal collectionData As String)
        Dim arrayString As String()
        Dim separator As String() = {",", "\n", " "}
        Dim attachmentList As New List(Of AttachmentModel)
        arrayString = collectionData.ToString().Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For i As Integer = 0 To arrayString.Length - 1
            Dim attachments As New AttachmentModel()

            attachments.AttachmentID = Integer.Parse(arrayString(i).ToString().Trim())
            attachments.AttachmentPath = arrayString(i + 1).ToString.Trim()

            attachmentList.Add(attachments)
            i = i + 1
        Next

        lbAttachments.DataSource = attachmentList
        lbAttachments.DisplayMember = "AttachmentPath"
        lbAttachments.ValueMember = "AttachmentID"


    End Sub
```