# Parsing and getting specific values from CSV string

Tags: vb.net

I am having a string in CSV format. Please see my earlier question
[Parsing CSV string and binding it to listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865861/parsing-csv-string-and-binding-it-to-listbox)

I can add new values to it by some mechanism. Everything will be same except the new values will have numeric part = 0. Take example
I have this exsiting CSV string

```
1 , abc.txt , 2 , def.doc , 3 , flyaway.txt
```

Now by some mechanism i added two more files Superman.txt and Spiderman.txt to the existing string. Now it became

```
1 , abc.txt , 2 , def.doc , 3 , flyaway.txt, 0, Superman.txt, 0 , Spiderman.txt
```

What i am doing here is that this csv string is paased into SP where its splitted and inserted to db. So for inserting I have to take the files with numeric part 0 only rest will be omiited .Which will be further then converted into CSV string

Array will look like this

```
str[0]="1" 
str[1]="abc.txt"
str[2]="2"
str[3]="def.doc "
str[4]="3" 
str[5]="flyaway.txt"
str[6]="0"
str[7]="Superman.txt"
str[8]="0" 
str[9]="Spiderman.txt"
```

So at last i want to say my input will be

```
1 , abc.txt , 2 , def.doc , 3 , flyaway.txt, 0, Superman.txt, 0 , Spiderman.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
0, Superman.txt, 0 , Spiderman.txt
```

Comment: Why dont you use anything like a DataTable for this purpose instead of the String Array? It would be easier to add, remove items and to synchronize it with the Database.

Comment: Actually i am retrieving these values from DataTable itself and from there I am saving it in a Collection. This is basically on my requirement as I have to hold values for multiples in the same time. So I am extracting rows from datatable and convert it to CSV string and then save it to collection. this also prevents me to hit db again and again.
Anyways the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new values are always being added to the end of the input, all you need to do is search the string for the first `0` and then return it and everything after it using `string.Substring(Int32)`.

Comment: the combination of 0,txtfiles could be random. So substring will not work